# My nested if statement won't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm coding in C# WPF. My lecturer says all my catches must be nested and I have to check that the trade in price is not greater than then the purchase price, also nested within the catches. I got the catches working but when I added the if statement within the catches it wouldn't work. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here is the relevant part of my code.

```
        const decimal GST = .1m;
        decimal gstAmount, carPrice, tradeInPrice;
        private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                carPrice = decimal.Parse(vehiclePriceTextBox.Text);
                try
                {
                    tradeInPrice = decimal.Parse(lessTradeInTextBox.Text);

               try
               {

               if (decimal.Parse(lessTradeInTextBox.Text) > decimal.Parse(vehiclePriceTextBox.Text));
                   {  
                       MessageBox.Show("The trade-in price cannot be greater than the purchase price" + "Reason: " + theException.Message);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                    subAmountTextBox.Text = (decimal.Parse(vehiclePriceTextBox.Text) - decimal.Parse(lessTradeInTextBox.Text)).ToString();

                    gstAmount = (carPrice - (carPrice / (1 + GST)));
                    gstAmountTextBox.Text = gstAmount.ToString();

                    finalAmountTextBox.Text = (decimal.Parse(subAmountTextBox.Text) + decimal.Parse(gstAmountTextBox.Text)).ToString();
                   }

               }

                catch (FormatException theException)

                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number: i.e. integer or decimal no. \n" + "Reason: " + theException.Message);
                    Keyboard.Focus(lessTradeInTextBox);
                    lessTradeInTextBox.SelectAll();
                }
            }
                catch (Exception theException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error, GeneralTransform Error. " + theException.Message);
                    Keyboard.Focus(vehiclePriceTextBox);
                    lessTradeInTextBox.SelectAll();
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException theException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number: i.e. integer or decimal no.  \n" + "Reason: " + theException.Message);
                Keyboard.Focus(vehiclePriceTextBox);
                vehiclePriceTextBox.SelectAll();
            }
            catch (Exception theException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error, GeneralTransform Error. " + theException.Message);
                Keyboard.Focus(vehiclePriceTextBox);
                vehiclePriceTextBox.SelectAll();
            }
        }
```

I get these errors

> Error 3   ;
>   expected  E:\4C#B\AssignmentPart1\Luke_Beauchamp_Part_1\Luke_Beauchamp_Part_1\MainWindow.xaml.cs  54  24  Luke_Beauchamp_Part_1
>   Error 2   Invalid expression term
>   'else'    E:\4C#B\AssignmentPart1\Luke_Beauchamp_Part_1\Luke_Beauchamp_Part_1\MainWindow.xaml.cs  54  20  Luke_Beauchamp_Part_1
>   Error 5   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new
>   object expressions can be used as a
>   statement E:\4C#B\AssignmentPart1\Luke_Beauchamp_Part_1\Luke_Beauchamp_Part_1\MainWindow.xaml.cs  53  20  Luke_Beauchamp_Part_1
>   Warning   1   Possible mistaken empty
>   statement E:\4C#B\AssignmentPart1\Luke_Beauchamp_Part_1\Luke_Beauchamp_Part_1\MainWindow.xaml.cs  50  101 Luke_Beauchamp_Part_1
>   Error 4   The name 'theException' does not exist in the current
>   context   E:\4C#B\AssignmentPart1\Luke_Beauchamp_Part_1\Luke_Beauchamp_Part_1\MainWindow.xaml.cs  52  118 Luke_Beauchamp_Part_1

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to ask your lecturer for an example of what he means by "catches must be nested", because nesting them the way you're doing is truly awful. Like, not good practice *anywhere*, in *any* language.

Comment: @ObliviousSage Besides the problem, but still a good point; it hurts my eyes.

Comment: Most of my code was copied and pasted from his example. I agree that it looks awful. It's easier for me to understand if the catches are linear, not nested. The lecturer looked at my project, which had linear catches at the time and said he's fail my project if I didn't make the catches neste, then told me to copy from his example.

Answer (score 6):

You have a semicolon after your `if` statement, which immediately ends it. The other errors are a result of the following `else` not having a matching `if`.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't end an if statement with a semicolon. Just remove it and everything will be fine!